# How can I calculate the cost of the query, if there is a `between` condition?

Tags: relational-theory, relational-algebra, relational-calculus

How can I calculate the cost of the query, if there is a `between` condition?

```
Select *
From A 
Where A.id between 10 and 50
```

If Index not exists and there is only one condition:

1. Search in B+ tree to find the first block that meets the condition (Binary search).
   **Cost**: `log_2(b_A)`.
2. Search in the following blocks that meets the condition. (Suppose half of the blocks meet the condition). **Cost**: `b_A/2`.

   - If the condition was `Where A.id > 10`, then the cost would be: `log_2(b_A) + b_A/2`
   - If the condition was `Where A.id < 50`, then the cost would be: `log_2(b_A) + b_A/2`

What is the correct way to calculate cost of 2 ranges of the same field?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no index for A.id column, then database engine perform full table scan.  So O(N) operations are performed.

If there is a B+tree index for A.id then database optimizer may choose it, if it is better than full table scan.

In a B+tree all the leaf nodes/records are linked; a node may have more than 2 elements.  Because all the records/leaves are linked in order (asc|desc), to get matching value for given range, it is sufficient find the min record location then we can iterate sequentially till max value.

[For a b-order B+ tree, finding a record requires O(logb⁡(N))](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree). If there is a m matching elements for (10,50 ) range, if we assume DB engine follow the above said method, then it requires O(logb⁡(N))+O(m) operations to find matching rows.